# Mediaplayer freezes application in slow Internet

Tags: android

Mediaplayer freezes application when a user clicks a source item while using a slow Internet connection. Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut.

How can I address this for slow Internet connections? I want the application to not freeze when clicked. (There is no problem over normal internet connections.)

Comment: Could you show source of key handling? Have you tried to launch play in Service or background thread?

Comment: Reason: keyDispatchingTimedOut
    Load: 0.13 / 0.09 / 0.03
    CPU usage from 11611ms to 0ms ago:
    3.1% 856/system_server: 2.5% user + 0.6% kernel / faults: 1 minor
    1.4% 798/mediaserver: 0% user + 1.4% kernel / faults: 112 minor
    0.5% 1148/applicationname: 0% user + 0.4% kernel / faults: 1 minor
    5.2% TOTAL: 2.6% user + 1.8% kernel + 0.6% irq + 0.1% softirq
    CPU usage from 127ms to 640ms later:
    1.9% 856/system_server: 0% user + 1.9% kernel
    1.9% 887/InputDispatcher: 0% user +1.9% kernel
    1.9% 888/InputReader: 0% user +1.9% kernel
    3.8% TOTAL: 0% user + 3.8% kernel

Comment: It's not code neither answer to question s.

Comment: ONly freezes in the of start of song, doesnt in the middle.

Comment: reset() > setdatasoutce(link) > prepare()> start()

Answer (score 0):

Use asynctask and call media player process in doInBackground method.

```
 new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                    @Override
                    protected void onPreExecute() {
                        super.onPreExecute();
                        volumeToggle.setEnabled(false);
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                        prepareRadio();
                        return null;

                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                        volumeToggle.setEnabled(true);


                    }
                }.execute();
```